# IdentityServer3 implicit flow

Tags: identityserver3

I though mine is the simplest implicit flow test possible. Using the embedded option to finish a quick demonstration. Unfortunately it doesn't work fully. I don't get a token back.

I think this is the code that does most of the work.

**Client**

```
          new Client {

            RequireConsent = false,
            Enabled = true,
            ClientId = "implicitclient",
            ClientName = "Implicit Client",
            Flow = Flows.Implicit,
            RedirectUris = new List<string>
            {
                "https://localhost:44310/identityclaim"
            },

            AllowedScopes = new List<string> {
                Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                Constants.StandardScopes.Email,
                "test"
            },
        AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt
        }
    };
```

**Scope**

```
        var scopes = new List<Scope>
        {
            new Scope
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Name = "test",
                Description = "Test",
                Type = ScopeType.Resource
            }
        };

        scopes.AddRange(StandardScopes.All);

        return scopes;
```

**User**

```
        new InMemoryUser
        {
            Username = "User",
            Password = "secret",
            Subject = "1",

        }
```

**Authentication**

```
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44309/context",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "test" }
        });
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        // web api configuration
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        app.UseWebApi(config);
```

**Setup**

```
                    return builder.Map("/context",
                            app =>
                            {
                                app.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
                                {
                                    SiteName = "SiteName",
                                    SigningCertificate = CertLoader.Load(),
                                    Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                                            .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                                            .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())
                                            .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get()),
                                    RequireSsl = true,
                                    LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions { EnableHttpLogging = true,
                                                                          EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true}
                                });
                            });
```

**Current Status**

When I login to the embedded IdentityServer3 I see this.

```
 Client Application Permissions
 You have not given permission to any applications
```

When I try this URL in the browser hoping to get a token back I see an error.
I have carefully base64 encoded everything.

```
       https://localhost:44309/context/connect/authorize?client_id=c2FtcGxlYXBpY2xpZW50=&redirect_uri=aHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzMTAvY2xhaW1z&response_type=dG9rZW4=&scope=b3BlbmlkIGVtYWlsIG15V2ViQXBp&state=abc&nonce=xyz


  The client application made an invalid request.
```

Comment: The redirect_uri looks odd to me.

Comment: Yes. I changed to a non-encoded url. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

can you check  AllowedCorsOrigins after RedirectUris,

same time also in your request url client_id looks invalid

```
client_id= < id of the Client>
```

https://localhost:44309/context/connect/authorize?client_id=c2FtcGxlYXBpY2xpZW50=&redirect_uri=aHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzMTAvY2xhaW1z&response_type=dG9rZW4=&scope=b3BlbmlkIGVtYWlsIG15V2ViQXBp&state=abc&nonce=xyz

so it should like below

https://localhost:44309/context/connect/authorize?client_id=**implicitclient**&redirect_uri=aHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzMTAvY2xhaW1z&response_type=dG9rZW4=&scope=b3BlbmlkIGVtYWlsIG15V2ViQXBp&state=abc&nonce=xyz

Answer (score 1):

Your authorization request should be like that, https://localhost:44309/connect/authorize?clientId=implicitclient&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44310/identityclaim&reponse_type=id_token&scope=openid%20test&nonce=none

Don't encode your request to base64, browser will encode automaticaly the url.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp